# Binary search tree traversal that compares two pointers for equality

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, traversal

I'm reading the Cormen algorithms book (binary search tree chapter) and it says that there are two ways to traverse the tree without recursion:

> using stack and
>   a more complicated but elegant
>   solution that uses no stack but
>   assumes that two pointers can be
>   tested for equality

I've implemented the first option (using stack), but don't know how to implement the latter.
This is not a homework, just reading to educate myself.

Any clues as to how to implement the second one in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure thing. You didn't say what kind of traversal you wanted, but here's the pseudocode for an in-order traversal.

```
t = tree.Root;
while (true) {
  while (t.Left != t.Right) {
    while (t.Left != null) {   // Block one.
      t = t.Left;
      Visit(t);
    }
    if (t.Right != null) {     // Block two.
      t = t.Right;
      Visit(t);
    }
  }

  while (t != tree.Root && (t.Parent.Right == t || t.Parent.Right == null)) {
    t = t.Parent;
  }
  if (t != tree.Root) {        // Block three.
    t = t.Parent.Right;
    Visit(t);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

To get pre- or post-order, you rearrange the order of the blocks.

Comment: you start of with a while(true), yet I see no break nowhere?

Comment: @reinier: Whoops! Good catch. You need to break if you're not at the root in the last step. Fixed.

Comment: still impressed with the algorithm. Especially if you did this of the top of your head. +1

Comment: Well, someone should probably test this to make sure it's right. ;)

Comment: when binary tree only one node, our pseudocode cant visit the root, and isn't this pre-order traversal?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the nodes in the tree are references and the values are references, you can always call the static [ReferenceEquals method on the Object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) to compare to see if the references for any two nodes/values are the same.

Comment: This part I know, what I don't know is the rest, the 'traversal' part